# Heroku SSL - No certificate given is a domain name certificate

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I am already 3 hours fighting with setting SSL certificate for a Heroku app. I am following [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#customdomain-ssl), but when I run

```
heroku certs:add server.crt bundle.pem server.key --app my-app-name
```

I always get this error:

```
Resolving trust chain... failed
 !    No certificate given is a domain name certificate.
```

I have bought the SSL certificate at **DNSimple**. What's is still wrong, why am I missing. It makes me despair, even Google didn't help...

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the ZIP file I downloaded from my SSL provider contained 2 .crt files and I picked the wrong one when running the `certs:update`. Re-running with the other .crt file solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your certs and your bundle are not resolving properly, i.e. either the trust chain is broken (not all certs exist in bundle for domain -> intermediate CA -> root CA) or alternatively your cert is not valid for the domain that Heroku is expecting.

Make sure the *fully qualified domain name* in your cert matches the domain you are using.